# MySQL stopped asking for passwords

Tags: mysql, password

I'm currently experiencing a weird problem with one of my MySQL database servers:

It stopped asking for passwords when I try to access the database from local with the mysql command line tool.

I need a valid admin username. I also still need a password for remote access (i.e. from another IP). And I need a password when I - for example - access the database from a PHP script. But when I try to access the database from local host/commandline it will let me straight in to the data with my administrative users.

They (admin users) have passwords set - and as I mentioned - I still need to specify those when I try to access the data via PHP.

Changing the password didn't help.

Non-Administrative users need to specify their passwort, but that doesn't really help if they can get anywhere with "mysql -u root" (or another admin user account name).

(System Debian Linux Lenny, MySQL 5.0.51a)

Any ideas? Anything that explains this behaviour? I don't understand how this can happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you the sole admin of the system?

If not, I guess someone else has created a file named "**/root/.my.cnf**", containing login-credentials. Can you verify this?

Comment: Great, that fixed my problem. Looks like my colleague created such a file... *grr*

Comment: I can't blame your colleague for that - I (almost) always create such a file. :-)

Comment: Fixed for me too.

Comment: Is there a way to force the mysql client to prompt for a password even if ~/.my.cnf exists?

Comment: Nvm, found it. Use `mysql --defaults-file= ...`. It has to remain as a first arg, right after `mysql `, and contains an empty space for no defaults file.